# "Device password" required when adding a new profile

Tags: password, profiles

I'm trying to add a new profile to my Android phone, but during the profile setup I am asked to enter my device password:

> **Re-enter your password**
>
> Enter your device password to continue

I don't remember ever setting up a device password, so I have no idea what this password is, and where I can change/set it from the admin account.

It is not the main account's unlock PIN.

I can't continue the profile setup without the device password.

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Model: OnePlus 5
Android version: 9

Comment: Could you mention the phone model and Android version? Also, are you not using any lock screen (e.g. PIN, Password, Pattern)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Added the device info to the question. I do have a pattern lock screen, but in the profile setup, it's a text (alphanumeric) password that can be entered.

Answer (score 2):

Oneplus devices have a bug with device passwords.  There are a number of [community threads](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/oneplus-7-not-accepting-password-after-restart-even-after-entering-the-correct-password.1122733/) complaining about Device Passcodes not working

I also experience this on my OnePlus device.  As mentioned in the linked thread, the workaround is to reboot the device any time you are told the device password fails.  I have to do this every other time the phone turns on.  I can't boot the device as the device passcode is constantly rejected as incorrect, and yet rebooting the phone any trying again will work first time.

Sadly this workaround fails for the scenrio you are describing, creating a new user profile will constantly reject the device password, rebooting doesn't resolve this for me in this scenario. What's especially annoying is, when cancelling out of the create new user screen, you are prompted for the device passcode to get back into your own account, and this works.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a solution to this other than the reports of factory resetting the phone solving the issue.  I have personally put up with this for too long on multiple OnePlus devices and won't be buying OnePlus again.